# Problema al crear boton con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Bien, necesito ayuda para crear botones que a la hora de editar el atributo se muestre como texto en el botón, lo logré, en el primero, pero cuando agrego mas botones no se visualiza se mantiene estático y deseo que el atributo que coloque en este caso precio sea el nombre que se visualice en cada boton.

```
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input id="myInput" type="submit"  precio="15" >
<input id="myInput" type="submit"  precio="25" >
<script>
        var valor = $("input").attr("precio")
        document.getElementById("myInput").value = valor;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y lo que muestra es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes cambiar el atributo value del input tipo submit, de esta forma:

```
<input id="myInput" type="submit"  precio="15" value="15" >
<input id="myInput2" type="submit"  precio="25" value="25" >
```

También te recomiendo que les coloques id's distintos, así puedes llamar al comando jquery

```
$('#myInput').val($('#myInput').attr('precio'));
```

O incluso si lo prefieres puedes nombrar las etiquetas con una clase y luego modificarlo con jquery de esta forma:

```
$('.clase-input').each(
 function(){
  $(this).val($(this).attr('precio'))
 }
);
```

Resumiendo, esto debería funcionar...

```
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input class="clase-input" id="myInput" type="submit"  precio="15" >
<input class="clase-input" id="myInput2" type="submit"  precio="25" >
<script>
        $('.clase-input').each(
         function(){
          $(this).val($(this).attr('precio'))
         }
        );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Básicamente tu error está en que quisiste cambiar el value de una etiqueta utilizando su id, pero el id es un identificador único por lo que solo una etiqueta puede tenerla, para modificar un grupo de etiquetas es preferible usar clases (class).

Comment: Amigo, lo logre solucionar, otra cuestion y disculpa el fastidio, me puedes decir como puedo, contatenar el texto del boton , mas otro texto? Soy nuevo en esto :(

Comment: Debes utilizar el operador "+", como sumando texto con texto, así $(this).val( $(this).attr('precio') + "texto" ) . Esto funciona para datos de tipo string por lo que quizá debas tranformar el valor de precio a string; $(this).val( $(this).attr('precio').toString() + "texto" )

Comment: Lo que hay en `precio` sería redundante, se puede usar el valor del atributo `value` y así se simplifican las cosas, ¿no?

Comment: Exacto. Incluso si colocas en `value` el mismo valor que aparece en `precio` no seria necesario incluir el script, ya que el texto que muestra el botón es precisamente el dato que se aloja en `value`.